# PyCloudinary "Invalid value for parameter kind" while trying to upload to Cloudinary

Tags: python, cloudinary

I'm trying to use [the quickstart guide](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/python_quickstart) with our test system.

```
 cloudinary.uploader.upload("https://cloudinary-devs.github.io/cld-docs-assets/assets/images/butterfly.jpeg", public_id="quickstart_butterfly", unique_filename = False, overwrite=True)
```

First I received `Field 'country' is mandatory and cannot be left empty"`, so I learned that I need to [add meta data](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference) to the call:

```
 cloudinary.uploader.upload(..., metadata="country=de|")
```

Another gotcha here is that you will need to use the `external_id` values for the metadata fields and not the ones displayed in the UI of Cloudinary. Also be aware that multi-select fields need to be handed over as lists:

```
 cloudinary.uploader.upload(..., metadata="country=de|language=[\"without_language\"]")
```

But now above error message keeps being thrown and I have no clue what `kind` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of pain I figured out that the message simply means that something with your metadata is wrong.

[Here](https://githubhelp.com/cloudinary/cloudinarydotnet/issues/318) I learned that the message is ambiguous and usually means that you have a wrong key in your metadata parameter rather than a wrong value for a non-existent parameter `kind`.

Comment: yes, also metadata is only mandatory during upload if you've set up the metadata that way, if you do not need to set it during upload, simply turn off the mandatory toggle for the metadata.